# Get the smallest date from table with unique records in sql server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, unique

I have table say VendorReport in this table i have three columns ID,PrefixId,Download_date
data in my table is as follow

```
ID      PrefixId Download_date

1   VIS017  28-09-2012
2   VIS028  29-09-2012
3   VIS035  29-09-2012
4   VIS028  30-09-2012
5   VIS028  29-09-2012
6   VIS028  01-10-2012
7   VIS025  30-09-2012
```

i want the unique PrefixId records with smallest date as show below

```
1   VIS017  28-09-2012
2   VIS028  29-09-2012
3   VIS035  29-09-2012
4   VIS025  30-09-2012
```

so i have tried this query but not getting expected result.

```
select VendorReport.PrefixId,VendorReport.Download_Date from VendorReport
join (select PrefixId, MIN(Download_Date) d_date from VendorReport group by PrefixId) t2 on VendorReport.PrefixId= t2.PrefixId order by VendorReport.Download_Date asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to get. Hope this will help:

```
WITH T AS
(
select 
     VendorReport.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PrefixID 
                        ORDER BY Download_date, ID) as RowNum
from VendorReport
)
SELECT ID,PrefixId, Download_date 
FROM T 
WHERE RowNum=1
Order by Download_Date DESC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c929/5)

Answer (score 1):

I'M new in sql server
  pls try this

```
select prefixId,min(download_date) as download_date from #abc group by prefixId order by prefixId asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..............

```
select Row_number() over ( order by x.Download_date),x.PrefixId,x.Download_date
(
select PrefixId,Min(Download_date)  Download_date
from 
VendorReport 
group by Prefixid
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
create table #VendorReport(
 ID int,
 PrefixId nvarchar(50),
 Download_date datetime
)


insert into #VendorReport values(1,'IS017','2012-09-28');
insert into #VendorReport values(2,'IS028','2012-09-29');
insert into #VendorReport values(3,'IS035','2012-09-29');
insert into #VendorReport values(4,'IS028','2012-09-30');
insert into #VendorReport values(5,'IS028','2012-09-29');
insert into #VendorReport values(6,'IS028','2012-10-01');
insert into #VendorReport values(7,'IS025','2012-09-30');

 select * from #VendorReport
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrefixId) as Id, PrefixId, min(Download_date) as Download_date from #VendorReport group by PrefixId


drop table #VendorReport
```